# Random Number Guesser - Cannot Input

Tags: java

I'm attempting a java challenge in which I guess a random number and the program tells me if it is correct.

However, the program stops at the while loop and tells me I can only input when the program is running:

```
public class javaChallenge1
{
    // Instance variables
    int number = 0;
    int guess = 0;
    boolean gameFinished = false;

    // Core variables
    Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
    Random rand =  new Random();

    public void sampleMethod()
    {
        number = rand.nextInt(100);
        System.out.println("Guess the number generated.");
        while (gameFinished = false)
        {
            guess = keyboard.nextInt();
            keyboard.nextLine();

            if (guess == number) {
                System.out.println("Congrats! You have guessed the number correctly.");
                gameFinished = true;
            } else {
                System.out.println("Bad luck. Try again.");
            }
            keyboard.nextLine();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: As some answers already state you assigned the value by accident instead of comparing it. A much safer approach can be `while(!gameFinished){...}` spoken: "While **not**  gameFinished".

Comment: @Michael Why did you change the code that was faulty? now the question has no meaning.

Comment: @JackFlamp yeah he has changed it..

Answer (score 4):

The error is on this line:

```
while(gameFinished = false)
```

You DO NOT check if the value is false but instead you assign the value false to your variable.

You should write `==` instead of `=` to **compare** values instead of **assigning** it

```
while(gameFinished == false)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to **compare** `gameFinished` against `false`, use the `==` operator:

```
while (gameFinished == false)
```

---

The following will **change the value** of `gameFinished` to `false`, then check if it is `true`. So the loop stops.

```
while (gameFinished = false)
```

Answer (score -1):

In while loop you should put the condition but you assigned the value. so please replace 
`gameFinished = false` 
to 
`gameFinished == false`

Comment: Answer with no explanation values nothing

Comment: sorry I am going to add the explanation